# In flutter，How to add a button at the bottom and top of ListView

Tags: flutter

How to add a button,this button bottom of screen and top of listview?
like this

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just do it using 'Stack' widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              height: 30,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Text('$index'),
            );
          },
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 40),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Text('FlatButton', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
              onPressed: () => {},
              color: Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```